# When building mopub sdk, cannot find symbol: class org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, mopub

I am building Mopub SDK as a module using Intellij Idea. 
I have copied test-assert-core-2.0M10.jar to libs folder under Mopub. However, when building it, the line `import org.fest.assertions.api.ANDROID;` shows red color at the word "`ANDROID`". Compilation error message says:

```
Error:(20, 31) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ANDROID
  location: package org.fest.assertions.api
```

Have searched, but found nothing about this particular error.
Anybody using Mopub under Intellij Idea can offer some hint? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution. I deleted all files under /mopub-sdk/src/test, and it builds successfully.